# What is the meaning of the classname from a lambda class in Java?

Tags: java, class, lambda

The classname of a lambda expression look like:

```
com.company.ParentClass$$Lambda$1/1096979270
```

In this sample:

- `com.company.ParentClass` is the containing class.
- `Lambda$1` is a static synthetic method in the containing class which implements the code
- `1096979270` a mystic number

Has this number any meaning? On every program run it is the same value. Sounds like it is build at compile time. But also a recompile does not change it.

Comment: Not sure, but I suppose the Lambda classname is an internal naming (like the inner embedded classes with the starting $1 for the fist inner embedded class, $2 for the second, etc.). And the "dash/xyz" could be the numeric name for the according Lambda.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of how you produced that, because I'm not able to reproduce the number. Also include the compiler that you are using, because this is very much implementation detail, and not specified in the language spec.

Comment: @Sweeper Runnable run = () -> System.out.println();
        System.out.println( run.getClass().getName() );

Comment: Oh you mean the class name of the object that implements the functional interface. I was thinking about the enclosing class of the lambda method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Lambda class names are kind of unpredictable.**

**Convention** : Lambda name is the name of package, followed by the enclosing class, followed by $$Lambda$, followed by a number, followed by a slash, followed by another number.

**Example** : `com.company.ParentClass$$Lambda$x/yyyyyy`

Here,

1. x is a sequential number per class.
2. yyyyyy is the hashcode of the Lambda.